# Help with SetTimeout function

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'm in the homestretch of finishing a site which is basically a souped up business advert but I'm having an issue with a set of li links that I am trying to slide left on mouseenter.

The problem is basically, the mouseenter function is way too sensitive.  Ive looked into the HoverIntent plugin but I understand it doesn't support mouseenter because mouseenter wasn't a supported jQuery function when the plugin was written.  So I've decided to go with SetTimeout function but I cant seem to get it to work properly.

Here's the portion of jQuery I'm trying to implement the SetTimeout function with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.home').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.home').stop().animate({left:'55%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_home:hidden').delay(600).fadeIn(600);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.home').stop().animate({left:'50%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_home').hide();

    $('.about').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.about').stop().animate({left:'55%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_about:hidden').delay(200).fadeIn(600);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.about').stop().animate({left:'50%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_about').hide();

    $('.contact').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.contact').stop().animate({left:'55%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_contact:hidden').delay(200).fadeIn(600);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.contact').stop().animate({left:'50%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_contact').hide();

    $('.services').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.services').stop().animate({left:'55%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_services:hidden').delay(200).fadeIn(600);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.services').stop().animate({left:'50%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_services').hide();
    });
    });
    });
    });

//Hidden icons
    $('#icon_home').hide();
    $('#icon_about').hide();
    $('#icon_contact').hide();
    $('#icon_services').hide(); 
});
```

html:

```
<div id="icon_home"><img src="Icons/home.png" width="60" height="60" /></div>
<div id="icon_about"><img src="Icons/about.png" width="60" height="60" /></div>
<div id="icon_contact"><img src="Icons/contact.png" width="60" height="60" /></div>
<div id="icon_services"><img src="Icons/services.png" width="60" height="60" /></div> 
<div id="thumb">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a rel="images/gallery/thumb/home.png" src="images/gallery/home.png" a href=" http://gmdcpa.com">
                         <img src="images/gallery/thumb/home.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li class="about"><a rel="images/gallery/thumb/about us.png" src="images/gallery/about us.png" a href="http://gmdcpa.com">
                          <img src="images/gallery/thumb/about us.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a rel="images/gallery/thumb/Contact Us.png" src="images/gallery/Contact Us.png" a href="http://gmdcpa.com">
                            <img src="images/gallery/thumb/Contact Us.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li class="services"><a rel="images/gallery/thumb/Services.png" src="images/gallery/Services.png" a href="http://gmdcpa.com">
                             <img src="images/gallery/thumb/Services.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

My question is, should I be combining these into one function?  If so, how should I go about doing so and what exactly should I do to implement SetTimeout so animations aren't called by quickly dragging mouse through the mouseenter area?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your HTML as well please. Also, is the first links `delay` different from the others on purpose?

Comment: it looks like on your mouse leave of home, is everything else that follows, you have `});` at the bottom... also use `stop(true,true)` to clear previous animations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is in one function

```
var sections = ['home','about','contact','services'];

$.each(sections, function(i,val) {
    $('.' + val).mouseenter(function() {
        $('.' + val).stop().animate({left:'55%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_' + val + ':hidden').delay(600).fadeIn(600);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.' + val).stop().animate({left:'50%'}, 1000)
        $('#icon_' + val).hide();
});
```

And there's a [plugin called `hoverIntent`](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to help with incidental mouseenters.

---

To make it more efficient, you could cache the DOM selections:

```
$.each(sections, function(i,val) {
    var main = $('.' + val);
    var icon = $('#icon_' + val);
    main.mouseenter(function(){
        main.stop().animate({left:'55%'}, 1000)
        icon.filter(':hidden').delay(600).fadeIn(600);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        main.stop().animate({left:'50%'}, 1000)
        icon.hide();
});
```

Also, if there's only one each of the `.home`, `.about`, etc, elements, or if there are more, but handler is only intended to affect the one that received the event, then you can replace:

```
$('.' + val).stop()
```

with:

```
$(this).stop()
```

Comment: I was under the impression that Hover Intent doesn't support mouseenter.  I'll try it out and report back.  Thanks for the code sir.

Comment: Hey, I implemented your code with no issues and there isn't a need for an intent plugin, taking out the delay did it. No random popups, no nothing, smooth seamless animations, thanks a ton! Here's the site if your interested http://testsite00.hostoi.com I decided to edit a few items but the slide functions are up and running!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a debounce .. take a look at this 
Remember this will call the handler after a particular timeout...

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Now to make it into a single section, you could define a second class for all say `menu`. and use `$(".menu").something()` to set the handler.

```
$(".menu").bind({
  mouseenter: $.debounce(250,function() {}),
  mouseleave: function() {}
});
```

If you want the debounce to happen on mouseleave also, you could use

```
mouseleave: $.debounce(200, function(){})
```

Remember that you have import the debounce extension for jQuery from that site. debounce is not built in into jquery.